# What is the difference between driver.switchTo().parentFrame() and driver.switchTo().defaultContent() method in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

What is difference between below two methods :

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

As per the specifications, **`driver.switchTo().parentFrame();`** invokes the following:

[image: Switch To Parent Frame]

Where, the [Switch to Parent Frame](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#switch-to-parent-frame) command sets the [current browsing context](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-current-browsing-context) for future commands to the **parent** of the **current browsing context**.

As per the *Java Docs* [`parentFrame()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#parentFrame--) method changes the focus to the parent context. If the current context is the top level browsing context, the context remains unchanged.

### driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

As per the *Java Docs*, [`defaultContent()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent--) method selects either the first frame on the page, or the main document when a page contains iframes.

Comment: That mean for example If i have 3 frames which are nested frames  i1, i2, i3. 

If my cursor currently in i3. By using parentframe() i can reach to i2 and i can reach to i1 by using defaultcontent()

Comment: @sreenathreddy Correct `If my cursor currently in i3. By using parentframe() i can reach to i2` but `defaultcontent()` will take you to the **main document** i.e. [**Top-level browsing context**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-top-level-browsing-contexts)

Answer (score 2):

**driver.switchTo().defaultContent();**

This will pass the control to the main document which contains the iframes

**driver.switchTo().parentFrame();**

This will pass the control to the imminent parent frame of the current frame

Lets understand it:

```
main body
{
frame1
{
frame2
frame3 (we are here currently)
}
}
```

Now using driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); will pass the control to main body

And using driver.switchTo().parentFrame(); will pass the control to frame1 .

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with multiple iframes in your webpage, then `driver.switchTo().parentFrame()` is generally used to switch the control back to the parent frame.

When you deal with pop-up dialog windows within your webpage, then `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` is used to switch the control back to default content in the window.

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly a difference :

**Scenario  :** When there are multiple frames and some of them are nested.

**iframeMain

    iframeParent

         iframechild**

Assume you are in **ifrmaechild** :

When you do `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();` : you will go to **iframeParent** .
But when you do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` : you will go to main HTML of page.
Note that in this case you will not go to **iframeMain**  .

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); in this case focus will move to parent frame of all nested frames. for Example, I have i1,i2,i3 frames are there which are nested frames. in this case, if I use default content()  when focus at i3, it moves to the i1 frame.

Comment: if you use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` from i3 , you will be moved to main HTML DOM tree.