# How to switch between multiple frames using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, frame

I want to send keys to Card Number, Expiration Date and CVV text fields which are in iframe.

Now what I observed is, when in the test case, whichever frame I write first to switch is located and the keys are sent and other two are ignored.

In below code, I mentioned expiration date frame first which is located but the card frame i.e. cddnumber id frame is not found.

```
cpp.fillintextfields.get(4).sendKeys("test@test.com");
WebElement es = driver1.findElement(By.id("CollectJSInlineccexp"));
driver1.switchTo().frame(es);
cpp.expdate.sendKeys("01/21");
driver1.switchTo().frame("CollectJSInlineccnumber");
Thread.sleep(2000);
cpp.cdnumber.sendKeys("4111111111111111");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Now when I mention cddnumber i.e. card number frame first as in code below and expiration date frame after that, card number frame is located and expiration date ones is not located.

```
cpp.fillintextfields.get(4).sendKeys("test@test.com");
driver1.switchTo().frame("CollectJSInlineccnumber");
Thread.sleep(2000);
cpp.cdnumber.sendKeys("4111111111111111");
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement es = driver1.findElement(By.id("CollectJSInlineccexp"));
driver1.switchTo().frame(es);
cpp.expdate.sendKeys("01/21");
```

Following are the TestNG traces of error given in short when I mention expiry date frame before card number frame:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id CollectJSInlineccnumber
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'KE5', ip: '10.6.6.105', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:885)
```

Please help me and suggest me any solution to tackle this issue so that all the frames can be located even though I write them one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to switch between two *child frames* of the same [*parent frame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096800/what-is-the-difference-between-driver-switchto-parentframe-and-driver-switch) (e.g. *Top Level Frame*) you need to switch to the **`defaultContent`** which is either the first frame on the page, or the main document when a page contains iframes and then switch to the second *child frame* as follows:

- First code block:

  ```
  cpp.fillintextfields.get(4).sendKeys("test@test.com");
  WebElement es = driver1.findElement(By.id("CollectJSInlineccexp"));
  driver1.switchTo().frame(es);
  cpp.expdate.sendKeys("01/21");
  driver1.switchTo().defaultContent();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver1.switchTo().frame("CollectJSInlineccnumber");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  cpp.cdnumber.sendKeys("4111111111111111");
  ```
- Second code block:

  ```
  cpp.fillintextfields.get(4).sendKeys("test@test.com");
  driver1.switchTo().frame("CollectJSInlineccnumber");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  cpp.cdnumber.sendKeys("4111111111111111");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  driver1.switchTo().defaultContent();
  WebElement es = driver1.findElement(By.id("CollectJSInlineccexp"));
  driver1.switchTo().frame(es);
  cpp.expdate.sendKeys("01/21");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Multiple iframe tags Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533101/multiple-iframe-tags-selenium-webdriver/48540002#48540002)