# How to find and interact with multiple elements within multiple frames on reCAPTCHA demo page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I switched to a frame inside a frame with selenium, and I accessed to that frame, but I'm unable to find elements inside the frame using `find_element_by_tag_name` or `find_element_by_xpath`, I'm sure the element exists, but I cannot find it and click on it with selenium.

**page > frame1(elements: checkbox) > frame2(elements: imgs , buttons)**

There are buttons in frame2 I want to click on it, and frame2 shown after checkbox clicked. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(r"C:\Users\[profilename]\Desktop\devloper\selenium\gecko")
driver.get(url)

sleep(10) #to make sure that everything loaded

#the first frame (success to access and clicked):
driver.switch_to.frame(0) 
click1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"anchor\"]")
click1.click()

sleep(5) #to make sure that everything loaded

iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

sleep(3)

frame2_element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
frame2_element.click()
```

Error msg:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element
```

I used `find_element_by_tag_name` and before that i tried XPATH and it had same error.

I tried hard to explain everything i'm not good with explaining things to people so i hope u understand me, and please tell me what to do :( .

> The url is : [reCAPTCHA demo](https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox-explicit.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *checkbox* element with in the [reCAPTCHA demo](https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox-explicit.php) page is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the *checkbox* you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.

Next, to click on the *Submit* button:

- You need to [switch to the `default_content`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937155/how-to-switch-between-multiple-frames-using-selenium-and-java/61979643#61979643)
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.

---

### Solution

You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox-explicit.php")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor')]")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='form-field']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Multiple iframe tags Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533101/multiple-iframe-tags-selenium-webdriver/48540002#48540002)

---

### Update

As per your recent comment update *this element that i want to click on //*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]* to click on the *reCAPTCHA audio button* you can use the following *Locator Strategies*:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to click on elements within an iframe to enable the captcha through the audio using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077053/how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-iframe-to-enable-the-captcha-through-the-audi/59078719#59078719)

Comment: thx for trying to help me out, but it didn't work, i edited your code to make it work but still. i think you understood my idea wrong, i meant by frame2 this frame: [link](https://i.ibb.co/5jbdLwR/Screenshot-2020-05-25-re-CAPTCHA-demo-I-m-not-a-robot-checkbox-Explicit-render.png). as i saw reCaptcha has two frames the first one is checkbox ease to click, but frame2 is the issue. if u did understand my idea, i'm sorry but it didnt work and i got two errors the first: from the website: `Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.` this came when the recaptcha passed

Comment: the second error : `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="form-field" type="submit"> is not clickable at point (102,379) because another element <div> obscures it` it came from cmd, when i couldn't pass recaptcha. i will try to fix it, and thank you for trying help me out <3.

Comment: this element that i want to click on //*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"].

Comment: @Jawad Added the solution to click on the **recaptcha-audio-button**. Check out the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: it works thank you, i have been trying for days to do it i feel like i'm newbie. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the url, we don't know if the element exists or not, but if yes, you can try wait for it to load. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: as u saw i added sleep and i used wait.until but same error the url is : https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox-explicit.php , frame 1 is reCaptcher