# How to extract the src attribute of an iframe using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I use selenium webdriver with C#,

```
<iframe class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default" id="component-1105" name="ets_grd_02_IFrame" src="frm_01_master_training_plan.aspx?RID=196&amp;RIU=U&amp;_dc=1641984641351" frameborder="0" style="margin: 0px; width: 718px; height: 535px;"></iframe>
```

I need to get src attribute of this element. I can locate inside of this iframe and make operations on the form which is located inside that iframe but I can't get src attribute.

Comment: What have you tried so far and there is a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the iframe src attribute:

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); // call this or make sure you are not already switched to this iframe
string iframeSrc = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'component-')]")).getAttribute("src")
```

To interact with the iframe elements:

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'component-')]"))
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
// do somethind you like within iframe
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Make sure that your target iframe is not placed within some parent iframe.
Otherwise, you'll have to first switch to the parent iframe to access the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that currently you program have the visibility on the [*Top Level Browsing Context*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096800/what-is-the-difference-between-driver-switchto-parentframe-and-driver-switch/51098090#51098090) i.e. within the [*parent frame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175323/switching-back-to-parent-frame-after-its-no-longer-in-dom-in-selenium/51176558#51176558), to get the value of the `src` attribute of the *`<iframe>`* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the `ElementIsVisible()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("iframe.x-component[id^='component'][name^='ets_grd'][name$='IFrame']"))).GetAttribute("src"));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@class, 'x-component') and starts-with(@id, 'component')][starts-with(@name, 'ets_grd') and contains(@name, 'IFrame')]"))).GetAttribute("src"));
  ```