# How to click on the submit button within theform after clicking the recaptcha-anchor using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried every thing, XPATH, NAME, TAG_NAME, CSS_SELECTOR but it allways returns me this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='vote']/div[2]/div/form"}
```

Here is my code :

```
time.sleep(4)
form = navi.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='vote']/div[2]/div/form").click()
```

Here is the html code of the webpage :

```
<form action="https://www.serveursminecraft.org/serveur/" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="2184">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Confirmation du vote pour Chocolia - Farm2Win - Lots IRL</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><span class="label label-info">Vous pouvez voter seulement 1 fois toutes les <b>24 heures</b>.</span></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 18px;">Vous êtes sur le point de voter pour Chocolia - Farm2Win - Lots IRL, êtes vous sur ?</p><br>
                                                        <div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto 1em auto;">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LegdhkUAAAAAJG95xpN69eylHs3bT4wRikdDQzH"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirmer le vote"><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I want to select this line of code :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirmer le vote">
```

Here is a part of my python code :

```
WebDriverWait(navi,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a'[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(navi,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
time.sleep(4)
navi.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='vote']/div[2]/div/form").click()
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Check if `form` located inside `iframe` node

Comment: Please also post your python code. This may be a situation where you'll need Selenium Waits using a condition that the element exists and is clickable

Comment: I cannot find any `span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']` in the html above. Post the full url, or post the full HTML for that pager in question.

Comment: i didn't post the whole html code but this line of code is working it clicks on the right button, the code stops working a the line navi.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='vote']/div[2]/div/form").click() and the error is no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='vote']/div[2]/div/form"}

Comment: The idea is: if you post the full html, or the url, we can check what elements are/aren't in the iframe, and when to get in, or out of the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

While interacting with the [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502835/7429447) you have switched to the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447).

Next, to click on the element `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirmer le vote">` you have to shift *Selenium*'s [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) back to the [**default** content (or parent_frame)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51098090/7429447) using either of the following lines of code:

- Using *`default_content()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  ```
- Using *`parent_frame()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
  ```

Now you can invoke the click as follows:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn.btn-success[value='Confirmer le vote']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-success' and @value='Confirmer le vote']"))).click()
  ```